# Building Boost BCP

Tags: c++, boost

I was trying to build [Boost C++ Libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries) for last two hours and stopped without any result. Since I am new to C++, I am unable to get the build right. How can I build it correctly using Visual Studio 2008?

I need to use the BCP tool to extract a subset of library. So I need to build BCP first, right? How to do this? When I tried to build it, I got the following error

> *fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_37.lib'.*

Where can I get the above given library file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, you need to have the proper PATH, INCLUDE and LIB environment variables in your command shell. For this, call the file "`vcvarsall.bat`" (or similar) with parameter:

```
vcvarsall.bat x86
```

Next you have to build bjam (you can also download it from the Boost page, but it's almost as quick). Go to the `tools\jam\src` folder in Boost and type:

```
build.bat
```

It should produce a subfolder `bin.ntx86` that contains bjam.exe. For convenience, copy it to the Boost main folder. Next, you can build bcp. Go into the `tools\bcp` folder and type:

```
..\..\bjam.exe --toolset=msvc
```

Back in the Boost main folder you can then build any library you wish:

```
bjam toolset=msvc –-with-{library}
```

where `{library}` is one of the libraries to build. All buildable libraries can be shown with:

```
bjam –-show-libraries
```

There are many more bjam build parameters. Some parameters with keywords you can specify are:

```
variant=debug|release
link=shared|static
threading=multi|single
```

An example would be:

```
bjam toolset=msvc –-with-filesystem threading=multi variant=debug stage
```

For more infos, visit the [Boost documentation pages](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs).

Edit: Updated link to point to most recent Boost documentation

Edit: Corrected options --with-{library} and –-show-libraries

Comment: It's `--with-{library}` and `--show-libraries`. Two '-', not one.

Comment: Thanks KTC, the documentations says the same. I corrected the answer.

Comment: There are some issues using these instructions with boost 1.46, including the absence of `tools/jam` and [bcp build failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010116/building-boost-with-mingw-gives-argument-error).

Comment: Workaround for tools/jam being absent (in 1.48 at least); run bootstrap.bat, it copies bjam to the main boost folder for you.

Answer (score 141):

The current version of Boost (1.50.0) uses Boost.Build. The new workflow for building bcp is as follows:

from the root Boost directory, type:

```
bootstrap.bat
```

Then, once Boost.Build has been built, type:

```
b2 tools/bcp
```

Comment: The resulting binary is found at dist/bin/bcp.

Comment: I've done 3 steps: 
`> bootstrap.bat  
> .\b2  
> .\b2 tools/bcp`  
And then I was able to use it: 
C:\Users\pedro\dev-VS2008\boost_1_59_0>dist\bin\bcp boost\tokenizer.hpp C:\Users
\pedro\dev-VS2008\MyProject\boost_1_59_0

Comment: Might be worth noting on linux you may need to execute the second command as `./b2 tools/bcp`. Small detail but may throw less experienced users.

Comment: I thought Linux used shell scripts, not batch files. Also, if you're using Linux, then you're automatically no longer "less experienced"

Answer (score 3):

I extracted the source: https://github.com/district10/cmake-bcp (You don't need to configure BOOST, cause all source code are included already).

On Linux, `cmake` + `make` to build:

```
# cd source_dir
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

On Windows: CMake-GUI + Visual Studio to build. Need help? See [HOWTO: Win + CMake + Visual Studio 2010](https://github.com/district10/cmake-templates/issues/1).

My executables (https://github.com/district10/cmake-bcp/releases/tag/2.0):

- Windows: [https://github.com/district10/cmake-bcp/releases/download/2.0/bcp.exe>](https://github.com/district10/cmake-bcp/releases/download/2.0/bcp.exe%3E) (3.81 MB)
- Linux: https://github.com/district10/cmake-bcp/releases/download/2.0/manylinux_bcp (1.02 MB)
- macOS (x86): https://github.com/district10/cmake-bcp/releases/download/2.0/macos_x86_bcp (801 KB)
- macOS (m1 chip): https://github.com/district10/cmake-bcp/releases/download/2.0/macos_arm_bcp (2.22 MB)

---

Tip: If you come across linking problems on Windows when using Boost, go check the `boost/config/auto_link.hpp` and you'll understand. To resolve this, you can just comment out the whole file.

Comment: Kudos for providing the binaries! Saved me probably 8 hours of compiling.

Comment: By the way, compile time is less than 1 minute. It's just boost bcp to compile, not whole Boost.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't need to build your Windows versions of bcp from source -- you can also download a binary version from http://www.boostpro.com/download, and skip all those steps.

(Or, at least, that's the case in theory -- I haven't tried it; I just found that page and this one while looking for a pre-built Linux version.)

Comment: Note: site requires registration to enable download.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to give you bcp by default.. you have to build it yourself anyway.

Comment: Windows bcp binary can be downloaded from here: http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.51.0/boost_1_51_tools.zip