# Building boost with MinGW gives "argument error"

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I am trying to build boost with MinGW and have downloaded `boost 1.45` and `bjam Version 3.1.18. OS=NT`

After cd'ing into the root of boost, I try to compile it with `bjam toolset=gcc --build-type=complete  stage` which doesn't work. This is the start of the error messages that are returned:

```
C:\boost\boost_1_45_0>bjam toolset=gcc --build-type=complete  stage
C:/boost/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2/build\configure.jam:145: in builds-raw
*** argument error
* rule UPDATE_NOW ( targets * : log ? : ignore-minus-n ? )
* called with: ( <pbin.v2\libs\regex\build\gcc-mingw-4.5.2\debug>has_icu.exe :  : ignore-minus-n : ignore-minus-q )
* extra argument ignore-minus-q
(builtin):see definition of rule 'UPDATE_NOW' being called
C:/boost/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2/build\configure.jam:179: in configure.builds
C:/boost/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2/build\configure.jam:216: in object(check-target-builds-worker)@410.check

---------- deleted 27 lines ---------

Jamroot:648: in build-multiple
Jamroot:634: in object(top-level-target)@96.generate
C:/boost/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:732: in generate-really
C:/boost/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:704: in object(main-target)@628.generate
C:/boost/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:735: in load
C:\boost\boost_1_45_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import
C:\boost\boost_1_45_0\tools\build\v2\kernel\bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build
C:\boost\boost_1_45_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

I'd appreciate any hint as to why I am getting these errors.

Comment: Why is that program so confused about whether to use / or \.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link might be helpful, it appears to be the same problem:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/64146

To summarise: you must use the **bjam version included with boost 1.45**.

And:

*Still, isn't it wrong that the bjam build linked 
directly above the 1.45 download link can't build 1.45?*

According to that link, don't use the Boost Jam link on the Boost downloads page. (Ie the version you have)

Comment: Really? I see more problems coming :-)

Comment: Yes, I was able to build bjam and then to build boost. Thanks for the pointer.