# A portable boost.xpressive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-xpressive

I want to use Boost.Xpressive in my C++ homework, and contain it in my source. But the whole boost header file is 70MB+, so is there any standalone xpressive distribution that contains only dependent files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bcp`. http://www.boost.org/tools/bcp/index.html.

it allows you to pull a header and all of its dependencies into a separate directory. Which will be much smaller than the whole boost library!

I don't know specifically, but the command line you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
bcp xpressive /foo
```

Comment: how to build bcp? I found an answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440585/building-boost-bcp, but I didn't find a /tools/jam/ folder under Boost directory.

Comment: Good question. As far as I can tell, it may just be a matter of running `bjam` in the tools subdirectory of the boost source.