# How to find out what dependencies (i.e other Boost libraries) a particular Boost library requires?

Tags: c++, boost

For any C++ Boost library, how can one find out which Boost library(ies) it requires ?

Example (not necessary a working example though): Boost library "test" requires Boost library "date_time".

Regards,

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you have a boost library, why would it need other boost libraries?

Comment: One must look deep into their own soul, and/or check the documentation. Typically, Boost does includes rather well (both of headers and `#pragma lib`), so you rarely have to worry about this.

Comment: @unwind, reminded me of "GNU is Not Unix" :)

Comment: @Cornstalks: ... in the question description :)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440585/building-boost-bcp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

boost comes with a tool to gather the dependencies of a library.

It is called [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html). If you just want a list of files, you have to use the --list option.

Comment: It has happened to me as well. Especially, with questions with short answers, like these.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find out those dependencies to isolate the components your software requires, you can use [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) (Boost Copy)

It copies selected boost libraries and all its dependencies to a target location.

Eg

```
bcp regex /foo
```

copies the complete `regex` library and its dependencies to `/foo`

Disclaimer: I do not have any practical experience with bcp.

EDIT:
If you only want to check on which compiled library a compiled library depends, you can either use `ldd <boost_library_filename>.so` on Linux or [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

A modern solution is to use [boost
Dependency Report](https://pdimov.github.io/boostdep-report/) (available starting from boost v1.66.0).