# Use only property tree from boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, qt-creator, boost-propertytree

I need to parse a large XML file using property tree in boost libraries. How to use them ONLY instead of including the whole boost libraries?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10818989/453271 can help. In short, you can minimise boost libraries set by including only those that `Boost.PropertyTree` depends on. You'll still need "core" headers with common preprocessor definitions etc.

Comment: @AndriyTylychko there's one more issue, I can't include it in my qt project and it gives me error including some files like this one:
mini-boost\libs\mpi\src\python\collectives.cpp:14: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/python.hpp': No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for you whatsoever to include the whole boost libraries. For example, if you look in the quick tutorial in the [appropriate boost documentation page for XML Property Trees](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/property_tree/tutorial.html), you see that you only need to include the following:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
```

In order to get the fully functional tutorial code compile error-free.

So, this answers your question:

> How to use them ONLY instead of including the whole boost libraries?

**But, in case you actually meant *having to package/deploy the whole boost libraries*** in contrast to *including the whole boost libraries*, then you have [the *bcp* tool, itself a part of boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) (also mentioned [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818717/how-to-find-out-what-dependencies-i-e-other-boost-libraries-a-particular-boost/10818989#10818989)) to aid you sift through the entire ordeal and know exactly what parts of the library are needed to use the property_tree library.

I have run this for you:

```
bcp --list property_tree
```

and the results are well... way to long to put in this answer. As in, the property_tree library itself is dependent on quite a large portion out of the entire boost libraries.

So, there won't be such a noticeable difference between packaging the entire boost as part of your project, and shipping only whats needed for property_tree to build.

Bottom line: If all you need is XML parsing capabilities and all of boost is too big for you then I suggest checking out one of the many XML libraries out there [such as TinyXML-2](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2) -- it is a "simple, small, efficient, C++ XML parser that can be easily integrated into other programs."

Comment: I want just only the property tree because the project is too small and there's no use adding the whole boost libraries so that I want to use only this library.

Comment: @AlaaAgwa Edited to hopefully better answer your pondering.

Comment: thanks alot, I did what you told me and it works but I can't compile it inside my qt project and it gives me missing files like this one: mini-boost\libs\mpi\src\python\collectives.cpp:14: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/python.hpp': No such file or directory

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist Nah. It sounds like OP is "compiling" the library. That can't work since all parts are header-only

Comment: Thanks alot @SkepticalEmpiricist, it works as you said :)

Comment: @AlaaAgwa Glad to have helped. BTW you have enough reputation to upvote together with accepting the answer, in case you wanted to.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I accepted it and upvoted it also ;)

Comment: @AlaaAgwa Cheers mate : )

Answer (score 2):

The direct question is: it's header-only, so no real meaning whatsoever.

What's way more important is this:

> I need to parse a large XML file using property tree

You need to pick one:

1. I need to parse a large XML file
2. I need to [...] use [red.] property tree

Boost Property Tree is **NOT** an XML library. If you need to parse general purpose XML, you can't use Boost Property Tree or you'll regret the choice pretty soon. See [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)`