# determine exact set of files necessary to build certain boost module

Tags: boost

For example, if I have downloaded the boost archive, I could delete `boost/fiber` and still build `container`, but I could not delete `boost/move`. How do I determine the exact set of files necessary to build a given module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out what dependencies (i.e other Boost libraries) a particular Boost library requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818717/how-to-find-out-what-dependencies-i-e-other-boost-libraries-a-particular-boost)

Answer (score 0):

`bcp --list-short <module_name>`